# How should I construct this MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a database with four tables:

```
users
- id
- name

sessions
- id
- title

sessions_users
- id
- sessions_id
- users_id

session_feedback
- id
- sessions_id
- users_id
```

Users are set to attend certain sessions (by adding their id to the `sessions_users` table). Users are also expected to leave feedback on a session. When done, the id of the session (`sessions_id`) and the id of the user leaving the feedback (`users_id`) is entered into the `session_feedback` table.

Given a particular user's id, I can't figure out how to select the sessions that have **not** had feedback yet (i.e. there is no entry in `session_feedback` containing both the `sessions_id` and the `users_id`). I.e. I need to select all sessions that have feedback pending.

Can anyone help at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a LEFT join.

```
SELECT s.* FROM sessions s
LEFT JOIN session_feedback sf ON sf.sessions_id = s.id
WHERE sf.session_id IS NULL
```

The query simply retrieves all records from the `sessions` table where there is no link to the `feedback` table (thus giving you sessions without feedback). If you want to include sessions that have users where there is no feedback.

```
SELECT s.* FROM sessions s
INNER JOIN sessions_users su ON su.sessions_id = su.id
INNER JOIN users u ON su.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN session_feedback sf ON sf.users_id = u.id
WHERE sf.session_id IS NULL
```

To further improve *or tighten* the query, just add to the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you wanted? This will return all sessions ids and titles that have not had feedback yet.

```
    select sessions.id, sessions.title
    from sessions where sessions.id NOT IN 
        (select sessions_id from session_feedback)
```

And for a specific user:

```
    SELECT sessions.id, sessions.title
    FROM sessions INNER JOIN sessions_user on
        sessions.id = sessions_user.sessions_id
    WHERE sessions.id NOT IN (select sessions_id from session_feedback)
    AND sessions_user.users_id = [given user id]
```